# IMovie06' Not working anymore because of Yosemite

Tags: macos, imovie

I upgraded to Yosemite and now my Imovie 06' will not work.

I need to open and finish projects that are due in three weeks. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to upgrade your iMovie version through the App Store to the version supported by 10.10

Answer (score 1):

Why not reinstall Mavericks and restore your backup from before the upgrade so you can finish your urgent work? You might even just get an external USB drive and just install Mavericks (or the original OS that came with your Mac) and boot from that OS to finish your projects.

You could then choose which OS to boot by holding the option key down at startup and just move the project files and media you need to the older OS.

Long term, an upgrade to a newer iMovie might be best, but not at the expense of learning new tools for projects that you know don't need the new features or learning curve.

Comment: You should never try to recover a backup from a higher OS to a lower OS. I have seen that cause plenty of issues for users in the past.

Comment: @ProfFrnswrth Thanks - I edited that in in case people assumed I meant that. Time Machine will refuse to restore a newer backup so I didn't think it needed qualification at first. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can still launch it by viewing package contents in Finder and then launching it from:
 Contents > MacOS > iMovie HD

Comment: Wrong. Doesn't work. this is a work around for beta version of Yosemite. Now obsolete.